Show that if $N=R_3(k,k,k)$, then ${N\choose k}\Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{{k\choose 2}-1}\geq 1$.
I'm trying to solve this graph theory problem using Ramsey numbers. I know that if $n\leq R_2(k,k)$ then ${n\choose k}2^{1-{k\choose 2}}\geq 1$, and that $$N = R_3(k,k,k)\leq R_2(R_2(k,k),k),$$ but I don't know what to do beyond this and if I'm on the right track. I would really appreciate some help finishing the proof!

The idea is just repeating the proof for $R_2(k,k)$. i.e. we're going to $3$-color randomly the edges of $K_N$ in a way where each edges is independently chosen a color, each with probability a third. Then, the expected number of monochromatic $K_k$'s is exactly
$$3\binom Nk\left(\frac13\right)^{\binom k2}$$
Since there are $\binom Nk$ copies of $K_k$, and for each of the three colors, the probability of it being monochromatic in that color is $3^{-\binom nk}$. If that expected number was less than $1$, there would be a way of coloring all the edges of $K_N$ such that there are no monochromatic $K_k$'s, therefore, by definition of $N$ we must have that this expected number is at least $1$. This is exactly what the question asks

Oh that's so simple, thank you so much!

No problem! Remember to accept the answer if you are satisfied!
